# Can't see the chat in Runescape

Tags: runescape

When I talk in game I can see it in the chat box. However I don't see the text appear over my character in the main playing screen. I must have disabled it but I don't know how to re-enable it. Where can I access those options to make my chat appear over my character's head?

Comment: What is the screen where you can see the chat box? The lobby? What exactly do you mean by "main screen"? I can't find a way to close the chat box in game

Comment: It's the playing screen where you see your charachter

Comment: Which one? Which screen is the one where you can see the chat box, and which is the one where you can't?

Comment: Ok you're looking at your screen. Theres a chat box a minimap, misc boxes and your main screen which you can select to attack things or bank. I can't see the text in the box where you can attack things.

Comment: OK, now I understand that you're in game, but I'm even more confused. Do you see a chat box, or not? Is there some other text you are unable to see?

Comment: @murgatroid99 i see the chat box and the text in it. I don't see the text appearing over my head tho

Comment: OK, now I think I understand what your problem is, and I edited your question to what you seem to be asking. However, I cannot reproduce this problem, so I don't know how to help.

Comment: There is a setting for this somewhere, and I think you set your Public Chat setting to "Hide" somewhere. However, as I am not familiar with the interface anymore, I do not feel comfortable answering.

Comment: @Unionhawk to humor you where might I find something Like that.

Comment: I'll log in to see if I can find it in the new interface. Give me a minute.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this problem. I can make it so that there's no chat in the chat window, but chat still appears over peoples' heads. Make sure your local chat filter is set to "On", though if it were "Off", then the reverse problem would have occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem has most likely been fixed. [The most recent patch notes](http://services.runescape.com/m=forum/a=869/c=6fachb5M4JI/sl=0/forums.ws?15,16,419,65115629) contain the line

> A bug where chat wasn't appearing above player's heads has been fixed.

As there is no way to disable chat appearing over your head in game, a bug was the most likely cause of the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Your private chat is turned on; just turn it off.